# How to access and convert pair value?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, auto

```cpp
vector<pair<int,char>> alpha;

for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    if (letter[i] > 0)
    {
        alpha.push_back(pair<int,char>(letter[i], (i+'A')));
    }
}

sort(alpha.begin(), alpha.end());

for(auto& val : alpha){
    string str = val.second;
}
```

I was trying to convert `map` value (which was `char` type) into `string` type using `auto`. I need to push those `char`s into `string`. How could I solve this?

Comment: This looks like C++ code, so I added the C++ language tag. If it's wrong the please [edit] your question to correct it.

Comment: As for the first loop, filling out the vector, I would recommend you use [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) instead.

Comment: And for the string creation I would use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a suitable [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Where do you use `std::map`?  Or are you using another definition of `map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```cpp
    string str;
    for(auto& val:alpha){
        str.push_back(val.second); // Append to back of string
    }
```

If you want to just append chars to the string.

Or you could do

```
auto str = string s(1, val.second); // 1 is the length of the string,
                                    // and val.second is the character to fill it with
```

If you want your strings to be just a single character long.

You could use `std::generate` and `std::transform` like others suggested if you think that makes your code more readable as other commenters has suggested (I don't think so in this case). I leave that as an exercise for the reader.